# XamDataGrid displays square char when bound to empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a XamDataGrid that is bound to a datatable object. This datatable object has information from a database. Some of the cells that get returned from the database contain strings, null values, and empty strings. For each empty string, the XamDataGrid displays a little white square. I have no idea how to get around this and I've been looking for a solution and nothing has worked.  Has anyone seen this before?

Values display the value in the cell. Null values keep the cell empty. Empty strings display the square. I would very much like it to display nothing (as in the empty string).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that it is actually an empty string and there there isn't a character or more in the string by checking the length of the string in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was actually putting in the end of string escape character '\0'. I had to actually change the database data type to be varchar(6) rather than char(6) and somehow that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The XamDataGrid will display whatever string is provided to it.  As such you should verify in the debugger that the string that is provided to the grid is actually empty and doesn't have non visible characters in it.